# How to make another batch file with variables using batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am making a batch file. (var1 is hi)

`echo if %var1%==%var1% goto label>>example.bat`

It says:

`if hi==hi got label`

I want example.bat to say

`if %var1%==hi goto label`

How do I do this?

Comment: What is Your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double % like this :

```
echo if %%var1%%==%var1% goto label>>example.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to anderstand what you want but try like this :

```
@echo off
set "Var1=Hi"

echo if %%var1%%==%var1% goto:label
```